# jQuery numbers scrolling effect up & down

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

How to develop effect like this
http://www.yourmoneysite.com/companies/asian-paints-ltd/ASIANPAINT


The numbers are scrolling up & down when value gets changed

thanks,
NJ

Comment: i thnk they hav slide down/up effect with the spans which have number 0 to 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this it is some how similar to the thing you want

http://bloggingsquared.com/jquery/flipcounter/

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flipCounter.1.2.pack.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>

 $("selector").flipCounter();
```